# Controller actions being executed as soon as the page loads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, coffeescript, haml

I'm using rails with devise, and angular with ng-file-upload.
I have two problems. first as soon as I go to the root of the website a POST request is executed to try to sign in the user with results in a 500 status code response.
It says it can't find the `users_url`, which makes sense because I don't have in my routes, what is weird is that request being fired.

Also using the ng-file-upload, when I load a dialog to upload a file, the dialog loads and it sends the request to upload the file directly. With no wait in between.

Why is this happening?
THis are the differents files being excuted in all this actions:

**app.coffee**

```
app = angular.module("inkorporated", ['ui.router', 'templates', 'rails', 'Devise', 'ngFileUpload', 'ngDialog'])
  .config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
  ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)->
    $stateProvider
      .state('home', {
        url: '/home'
        templateUrl: 'home/_home.html'
        controller: 'SearchCtrl'
      })
      .state('login', {
        url: '/login'
        templateUrl: 'auth/_login.html'
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
        onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', ($state, Auth)->
          Auth.currentUser().then ->
            $state.go('home')
            return
          return
        ]
      })
      .state('register', {
        url: '/register'
        templateUrl: 'auth/_register.html'
        controller: 'AuthCtrl'
        onEnter: ['$state', 'Auth', ($state, Auth)->
          Auth.currentUser().then ->
            $state.go('home')
            return
          return
        ]
      })
      .state('user', {
        url: '/user/{id}'
        templateUrl: 'users/_user.html'
        controller: 'UserCtrl'
      })
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home')
    return
])
```

**navCtrl.coffee**

```
angular.module("inkorporated").controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Auth',
  ($scope, $state, Auth)->

    $scope.config = {
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content")
      }
    }

    $scope.signedIn = Auth.isAuthenticated
    $scope.logout = Auth.logout

    Auth.currentUser().then(
      (user)->
        if !!user.email
          $scope.user = user
        else
          $scope.user = {}
        return
    )

    $scope.$on('devise:new-registration',
      (e, user)->
        $scope.user = user
        return
    )

    $scope.$on('devise:login', 
      (e, user)->
        if !!user.email
          $scope.user = user
        else
          $scope.user = {}
        return
    )

    $scope.$on('devise:logout',
      (e, user)->
        $scope.user = {}
        return
    )
    return
])
```

**avatarCtrl.coffee**

```
angular.module("inkorporated").controller("AvatarCtrl", ["$scope", "$stateParams", "Upload", "ngDialog"
  ($scope, $stateParams, Upload, ngDialog)->

    $scope.$watch('avatar',
      (avatar)->
        $scope.upload($scope.avatar)
        return
    )

    $scope.upload = (avatar)->
      Upload.upload({
        url: "users/avatar",
        fields: { 'id': $stateParams.id }
        file: avatar
      })
      .success(
        (data, status, headers, config)->
          $scope.closeThisDialog()
          return
      )
      return
    return
])
```

**application.html.haml**

```
!!!
%html{ "ng-app" => "inkorporated" }
  %head
    %meta{:content => "text/html; charset=UTF-8", "http-equiv" => "Content-Type"}/
    %meta{ name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" }/
    %title Inkorporated
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
  %body
    .container-fluid
      %header{ "ng-include" => "'nav/_nav.html'" }
    #page-content.container      
      %ui-view
```

Comment: Not clear what `can't find users_url` means. Presumably it is url used to make request and that request would be triggered by navCtrl. As for upload not clear what `no wait in between` means

Comment: The can't find users_url is not the important part, is that action are being fired as soon as the page loads. As soon as I go to the website `localhost:3000`, I can see that a `POST` request is fired to `http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json` and I don't know why that is going on. The other thing is that when I load a dialog that is using `ng-file-upload` it tries to upload a file as soon as the dialog opens, sending also a request to `http://localhost:3000/users/avatars` which is the address that I set up to modify the avatar

Comment: likely inside  `Auth.currentUser()` called in navBarCtrl. No code shown for that though. Your upload is bound to ` $watch` ...should check for newValue on that probably or re-think upload logic

Comment: @charlietfl that is part of the Devise service for Angular

Comment: But Devise is backend...your issue is with the angular code which runs in browser. That service is what would likely make that post request although I can't see what it does

Comment: This is the [angular-devise](https://github.com/cloudspace/angular_devise/blob/master/src/auth.js#L250) code that I'm reffering to. And again, the problem is not the 500 error, I know why is that happening.

Comment: ok...so can clearly see it makes request by calling login if not authenticated

Comment: probably want to use `isAuthenticated` in `navBar` instead. Then fix $watch which will fire on scope initialize also. Might also want to look into using `resolve` in routing

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see here, I think there's a very good chance that the `$watch` is being triggered by a model change on `avatar` when your dialog opens. You can pretty easily remove that watch and make that function more event driven. Looking at the ng-file-uplpad docs, it looks like there's a directive attribute to specify calling a custom function like `ngf-change="myFunction()"`

```
$scope.$watch('avatar', function(avatar) {
  $scope.upload($scope.avatar);
});
```

For the second part of your question, I'm curious to see what code is in the `SearchCtrl` being called on the landing page, that POST request could easily be related to something in there

Comment: The SearchCtrl is empty, is just the mere declaration of the controller